# Convert byte array to string in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, serial-port

I'm new to C# and I built an application that receives bytes from a Serial Port and parses the bytes.

In one scenario, the application receives an array of bytes that represents a string. My idea is to convert the bytes to string ad visualise the string into a text box.

With this code:

```
textSerialNumber.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readData.payload, 0, readData.payload.Length);
```

I obtain the string but there is a problem: the first byte receive on the serial port is a 0x00 ( it represents an ack ). When i convert the payload (ack + string ) the first character is a NULL and text box assignments fails.

If I modify the code to start form the first element of the byte array:

```
textSerialNumber.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readData.payload, 1, readData.payload.Length);
```

Also in this case the text box assignment fails.

I try to skip the text box assignment:

```
string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readData.payload, 1, readData.payload.Length);
```

But also int this case the encoding fails.

Any suggestion to find the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(readData);`

Comment: What does it mean "it fails"?

Comment: Fails means the the assignment procedure fails and the code reaches the catch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readData.payload, 1, readData.payload.Length - 1);`

Last argument is `count`, so if you start from 1, count has to be 1 less.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! It works! But the assignemts into the text box fails: this is my string : "V2_1928608331\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".

Comment: I found the problem. C# means that another thread try to modify the textbox.